# How to merge a created pivot table data back to the original database in python?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My original dataset includes Rating of Every Episode

[Friends TV Show IMDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWru.png)

What I want to do is get a average rating per season. So I created a pivot table

pivot = tv_show.pivot_table(index = ['Season Number'], values = ['Rating'], aggfunc = np.mean )
print(pivot)

[Average Rating per Season via Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcO1a.png)

Now I want to add this average rating per season back to my original data set (and add a new column 'Average Rating per season')

I cannot figure out how to do so.

Comment: `tv_show['Average Rating per season'] = tv_show['Season Number'].map(pivot)`.

Answer (score 1):

In addiction to Quang Hoang's comment, you can do it in one-step with:

```
df['Average Rating per season'] =  df.groupby('Season').Rating.transform(np.mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `pivot`, Why not use a `groupby` and then `transform` (prettify index to make assignable, use `.mean().reset_index()` if you need seperate dataframe) and assign to column?

```
df['Avg Rating'] = df.groupby('Season')['Rating'].transform(np.mean)
```

If you haven't yet imported numpy, then import with:

```
import numpy as np
```